# Deserialization of class with struct member from binary file

Tags: c#, deserialization

i have a problem with deserialization struct from binary file. My struct has another struct as property:

```
[Serializable()]
public struct Record : ISerializable
{
    public SensorInfo SensorInfo;
    public List<short[]> Frames;

    public Record(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        this.Frames = (List<short[]>)info.GetValue("Frames", typeof(List<short[]>));
        this.SensorInfo = (SensorInfo)info.GetValue("SensorInfo", typeof(SensorInfo));
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        info.AddValue("Frames", this.Frames);
        info.AddValue("SensorInfo", this.SensorInfo);
    }
}
```

SensorInfo structure:

```
[Serializable]
public struct SensorInfo : ISerializable
{
    public double Frequency;
    public int FramePixelDataLength;
    public int FrameWidth;
    public int FrameHeight;

    public SensorInfo(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        this.Frequency = (double)info.GetValue("Frequency", typeof(double));
        this.FramePixelDataLength = (int)info.GetValue("FramePixelDataLength", typeof(int));
        this.FrameWidth = (int)info.GetValue("FrameWidth", typeof(int));
        this.FrameHeight = (int)info.GetValue("FrameHeight", typeof(int));

    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        info.AddValue("Frequency ", this.Frequency);
        info.AddValue("FramePixelDataLength ", this.FramePixelDataLength);
        info.AddValue("FrameWidth", this.FrameWidth);
        info.AddValue("FrameHeight", this.FrameHeight);
    }
}
```

I'm using serializer with this code:

```
static public class RecordSerializer
{
    static RecordSerializer()
    {
    }

    public static void SerializeRecord(string filename, Record recordToSerialize)
    {
       Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create);
       BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
       bFormatter.Serialize(stream, recordToSerialize);
       stream.Close();
    }

    public static Record DeSerializeRecord(string filename)
    {
       Record recordToSerialize;
       Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
       BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
       bFormatter.AssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple;
       recordToSerialize = (Record)bFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
       stream.Close();
       return recordToSerialize;
    }
}
```

Serialization works fine, i get an output file. But when i try to deserialize it, I get only exception from bFormatter.Deserialize and deserialization fail.

```
Frequency not found.
```

Stream is not empty, I checked this.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Have you changed second `struct` after saving that file? Besides, you have an extra space for naming of `Frequency` in `info.AddValue("Frequency ", this.Frequency);`

Comment: Just the extra space is all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a whitespace for the properties `Frequency` and `FramePixelDataLength`, like "Frequency " and "FramePixelDataLength ".

Use this:

```
info.AddValue("Frequency", this.Frequency);
info.AddValue("FramePixelDataLength", this.FramePixelDataLength);
```

instead of:

```
info.AddValue("Frequency ", this.Frequency);
info.AddValue("FramePixelDataLength ", this.FramePixelDataLength);
```